# Kentico 8 On-site keywords - Daily report is not working

Tags: kentico

On-site keywords - Daily report is not working,I have enabled web analytics in setting but whenever I see report of pages, there is not showing tracking and activity. Graph is showing only one line on x-axis.

[image]

Comment: Only daily report is not working? Or whole web analytics? Did you enabled it with correct way? https://docs.kentico.com/k10/on-line-marketing-features/configuring-and-customizing-your-on-line-marketing-features/configuring-web-analytics/enabling-web-analytics

Comment: Now its working fine, I have unchecked this option "Log via JavaScript snippet:" in setting web analytics then its working fine.Because in smart search result web-part there is some code to checking this setting. and then code its not working when its checked.